# How to populate the rootviewcontroller tableview with an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am trying to populate the tableview with an NSMutableArray, and I am having a really hard time with it.

This should be simple I'm thinking, but I can't get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There are sooooo many tutorials around the net, and even on StackOverflow for creating a simple table view.  You should search around a bit!  Here's the first hit on Google: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uitableview-creating-simple-table-view.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to create an object implementing the UITableViewDataSource.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.yourArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    /* create your cell here */

    AnObjectFromYourArray *myObject = [self.yourArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row];

    /* fill the cell with the info in my object */

    return yourCell;
}
```

simple as that.

Greg